# Why unlocked_ioctl in file_operations returns long, while ioctl() from sys/ioctl.h returns int?

Tags: c, unix, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

The signature of unlocked_ioctl inside struct file_operations in  is

```
long (*unlocked_ioctl) (struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
```

while the man 2 ioctl says the signature of ioctl(2) is:

```
int ioctl(int d, int request, ...);
```

I know how the parameters get mangled inside the kernel, but why return type in kernel space is long, while the user space gets int? This creates a problem when I want to return a negative value as an error: because of a two-complement encoding, everything negative value I return is turned into -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you return a negative value from a `file_operations` function, the kernel interprets it as a negative `errno` (i.e. an error return). User code then gets `-1` as a return value, with `errno` set to the negation of your original return value. This has nothing to do with twos-complement.

Per [`man 2 intro`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), “introduction to system calls”:

> On error, most system calls return a negative error number (i.e.,
> the negated value of one of the constants described in errno(3)).
> The C library wrapper hides this detail from the caller: when a
> system call returns a negative value, the wrapper copies the
> absolute value into the errno variable, and returns -1 as the
> return value of the wrapper.

As an example, if you return `-ENOTTY` from `unlocked_ioctl`, the user program gets -1 from `ioctl` and `errno = ENOTTY`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. At first I guessed it happens, but experiment proved this conjecture to be wrong -- at least that's what it looked like. I just reexamined the code and it seems that I used another function that changed the errno in the meantime.

Comment: Where is this behaviour defined/documented?

Comment: This particular behaviour (translating a kernel’s negative errno to -1 in userspace) is documented here, under “Return Value”: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html